# Is Google Glass Mirror API dead?

Tags: google-glass, google-mirror-api

I've been trying to test Google Glass Mirror API but I guess it's dead since they've quit its development.

Requests are made to this url (https://www.googleapis.com/mirror/v1,), but it states "Not found". Playground itself is open, but doesn't send anything to the device.

Does anyone know if there's a way of overcoming this? Or if they changed the server location?

Sincerely,
Apidcloud

Comment: I meant the server where REST requests are sent to, not the documentation.

Comment: As far as I can tell, the Mirror endpoint still seems to be working. (Or at least my code using it isn't failing.) Can you update to add a code sample to illustrate what is causing the error?

Comment: It simply doesnt show anything on google glass. I've tried https://glass-python-starter-demo.appspot.com/# and a localhost server. I've set a google app with cliend id and all that but I don't know the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to access the exact URL you specified (https://www.googleapis.com/mirror/v1), it won't work. That isn't a valid endpoint itself for the API. All of the API calls are to URLs that start with that prefix. For example, once authorized, the URL https://www.googleapis.com/mirror/v1/timeline should get the timeline items for the authenticated user. Other paths either retrieve or take action.

If the playground is not sending anything to the device, that is usually an indication that you didn't auth the playground and the device against the same Google account. Make sure you follow the auth directions listed on the Playground page.

Comment: That does make sense. If I try to go to the url you suggested, I get 'Login required' error. The device was acquired for an on-going project, so one of my teachers used his google account on it. But, some days ago we've tried with his account and it also didn't work. Does factory reset allow me to set up the account again?

Comment: Factory reset did the work :) I've set with my own account and it's working so far! Thanks for the help